# how to separate secondary string from main string by swift macos?

Tags: swift

I need to separate the substring `bc` from the main string, but the result is returned: `bc,d,e,f`

```
let tokenx = "123 abc,d,e,f,"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "a(.*),")
let matches = regex.matches(in: tokenx, range: NSRange(tokenx.startIndex..., in: tokenx))
for match in matches {
    let swiftRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: tokenx)!
    print(tokenx[swiftRange])
}
```

Comment: Actually the result is supposed to be `,d,e,f`, the grouped pattern is *zero or more characters*  followed be a single comma which is the comma after the `f`.

Comment: Could you describe the pattern you are trying to match better? Is it always “bc” or is it always something following an “a” etc?

Comment: Your edited post shows the same behavior. `match.range(at: 1` displays the portion inside the parentheses which is ***zero or more (any) characters*** after an `a` and before a trailing comma. To separate `bc` you need something like `"a(bc).*"`

Comment: Thank you! - vadian, I want to edit it so it recognizes the first comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate *anything* between the `a` and the `first comma` you have to search for ***one or more characters which are not a comma*** inside the parentheses `([^,]+)`

```
let tokenx = "123 abc,d,e,f,"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "a([^,]+)")
let matches = regex.matches(in: tokenx, range: NSRange(tokenx.startIndex..., in: tokenx))
for match in matches {
    let swiftRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: tokenx)!
    print(tokenx[swiftRange])
}
```

A more specific pattern is `"a([^,]+),d,e,f,"`